The generalized likelihood ratio test of H0: µ<=µ0 v.s. H1: µ>µ0 with unknown σ
Assume:random samples in N(µ,σ²)
when null hypothesis(H0) is true,
why MLE is min{µ0,X̄} ?
How can get MLE in restricted parameter space(µ<=µ0) ?
please help me
